# QGIS and satellite images band combination

Tags: qgis, raster, remote-sensing

When I add a satellite images as a raster in QGIS:

1. Why the image is changed, it looks like it has only one band?
2. Where is a tool for band combination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the data are changed but I suspect that QGIS doesn't understand how to handle a multiband raster which has more than 3 bands so it defaults to gray-scale.

Once you have imported your raster, right-click on it and go to Layer Properties.  In the style tab you have the option to render as a single band or three band (RGB) image.  You can specify which bands to use for R, G and B and can tweak the min and max val

Comment: Hi Silvester! Ah! Now I see where is the layer properties. I have QGIS in Russian. Didn't notice it before. Everything works. Many thanks!

Comment: Would love to accept Silvester's answer, his answer did solved my problem! Thanks a lot. But how to accept his answer? Ok, I see now the tick button. Done!

Comment: Glad to help :)